# URL parameters are being removed by themselves automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, chart.js, html5-history

I'm attempting to add URL parameters to an Angular single page app in HTML 5 via Javascript using `history.pushState()`, like so:

```
var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?para=hello';

window.history.pushState({}, '', newurl);
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the parameter, it is immediately removed from the URL in the address bar. There's a split second where I see the parameter appear and disappear from the address bar. I think there is some other function/logic in my angular file that is removing it. Problem is, I don't know what it could be. My first assumption was some conflict with `$scope.apply()`, but there's only one `$scope.apply()` call that is made on the page and it doesn't occur while this function runs. The libraries I'm using on the page are:

`chartjs`
`angularjs`
`bootstrap`

If anyone knows or has an idea what could be causing the parameters to be ripped from the URL as soon as they're added, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Use the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to set the url parameters. For more infrormation see, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Comment: I implemented $location service like you suggested @georgeawg, but it looks like maybe adding the `<base href="/">` for $locationProvider to the head makes links no longer work. Would you know anything about that?